# if I use waitpid() after kill() with SIGTERM my program does not behave how its supposed. But it works if I dont use waitpid()?

Tags: c, fork, child-process, kill-process, waitpid

Im trying to close a receiver on a RPC client that is running on a child process giving it max. 5 seconds to finish its business. If I do it while using `waitpid()` to ensure the child process terminated gracefully after using `SIGTERM`, I can no longer restart the receiver with a `fork()`. the child process simply wont open the receiver application with execvp() anymore, and goes straight to the main menu of the application.
If I dont use `waitpid()` and just use `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM` with the `kill()` function, I can reopen the reciever again and receive messages from the dispatcher.

Example how I call the methods:
sub -> unsub -> sub ( this sub wont restart the RPC_Receiver if I used waitpid in unsub method )

Subscribe Method

```
void subscribeToDispatcher(CLIENT *clnt) {

    return_code = subscribe_1(NULL, clnt);
    
    if (return_code == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", PUB_SUB_RET_CODE[UNKNOWN_ERROR]);
    } else {
        printf("Subscribe status: %s\n", PUB_SUB_RET_CODE[*return_code]);
    }
    if (*return_code == OK) {
       
        //receivers childprocess
        printf("Starting the message receiver...\n");
        childPID = fork();
        char *args[] = {};

            if (childPID == 0) {
                execvp("./RPC_Receiver", args);
            }
        if(childPID == -1)
            printf("Error beim starten des Receivers. Fork() Failed.\n");
    }
}
```

Unsubscribe Method

```
void unsubscribeFromDispatcher(CLIENT *clnt) {

    return_code = unsubscribe_1(NULL, clnt);
    
    if (return_code == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", PUB_SUB_RET_CODE[UNKNOWN_ERROR]);
    } else {
        printf("Unsubscribe status: %s\n", PUB_SUB_RET_CODE[*return_code]);
    }
    
    if (childPID != -1 && childPID != 0 && *return_code == OK) {

        printf("Closing the message receiver");

        kill(childPID, SIGTERM);

        int childDead = 0;
        int status;
        
        for(int i = 0; !childDead && i < 5; i++){

            printf(".");
            fflush(stdout);
            
            if(waitpid(childPID,&status,WNOHANG) == childPID ) {
                childDead = 1;
                printf("\n");
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        if(!childDead)
            kill(childPID,SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

While loop that acts as navigation where I call the methods from the main Method.

```
 while (1) {
        menuNavigation(input);

        if (strcmp(input, "sub") == 0) {
            subscribeToDispatcher(clnt);
        } else if (strcmp(input, "unsub") == 0) {
            unsubscribeFromDispatcher(clnt);
        } else if (strcmp(input, "publish") == 0) {
            sendMessage(clnt);
        } else if (strcmp(input, "topic") == 0) {
            setTopic(clnt);

        } else if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("closing the application.\n");
            unsubscribeFromDispatcher(clnt);
            free(input);
            clnt_destroy(clnt);
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(input, '\0', sizeof(&input));
    }
```

Comment: Your expected/unexpected behavior involves code we cannot see (your snippets will not call fork after waitpid as far as I can tell). Can you do a [mre] that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @dratenik I call the Methods myself in a "menu" interface. what I do is: call subscribeToDispatcher, then call unsubscribeToDispatcher, then call subscribeToDispatcher again, in this situation when I call the method again after unsubscribing from the server, the child process wont start RPC_Receiver anymore with execvp. if I remove waitpid() and do it all again it works.

Comment: `char *args[] = {};`?  Have you **verified** via thorough **testing** that your `RPC_Receiver` process runs **reliably** with `argc` set to zero and `argv[0]` set to `NULL`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes the RPC_Receiver runs as expected without args. as it is from rpc.h it has its own automatically generated main method. it also runs in the first call to the sub method, and always runs if I remove waitpid() from unsub.

Comment: @Andrew has been a little light in his criticism there.  `char *args[] = {};` is not valid C, as C does not support zero-length arrays or empty initializers.  Moreover, even if your compiler accepts that as an extension, the result would not be a valid input to `execvp`, regardless of what the exec'ed program may do, because the argument list must be terminated by a null pointer.

Comment: I asked if you thoroughly tested it, not where it's from or what it's based on.  There are a lot of commonly-used methods such as getting the current executable name or command line that implicitly rely on having at least `argv[0]` set to a non-NULL value.

Comment: @dratenik I added some more input to the question, and my while loop that I use as navigation. Is that clear enough? I could also write a simple method that calls both subscribe and unsubscribe and subscribe again to reproduce how it happens, I tried to describe it in text for now with sub->unsub->sub.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I didn't even notice that part.  And that's undefined behavior since that's not an array of pointers terminated with a `NULL` pointer as expected by `execv()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you I will change that! Didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: @JohnBollinger it fixed my problem!! Thank you so much! but I dont understand why it always ran the first time, and only broke after killing the process and trying to run the execvp method again. Do you have an idea why that was the case?

Comment: the variable: `return_code` is used in multiple functions, however, 1) this hints it is a global variable, but should be local to each function.  2) there is no indication in the posted code as to how it is declared

Comment: in the `unsubscribe` function, what is `childpid`?  it is not declared anywhere nor set anywhere.

Comment: regarding: `menuNavigation(input);`  what is `input`?  what is the body of `menuNavigation()`?   Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you to debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 the return_code is a global variable. You are right I should be declared for each function, will fix that. ChildPid is a pid_t variable also declared globally so it can be used on both sub and unsub functions without having to send the reference around everytime. The problem has been fixed, it was the arguments array I was passing to execvp, it was not initialized and therefore had no null Pointer to flag the ending of the arguments array being used in the main method of the receiver application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnBollinger i fixed my problem. I will quote his in this answer so its more visible in case someone comes across the same problem.

> char *args[] = {}; is not valid C, as C does not support zero-length arrays or empty initializers. Moreover, even if your compiler accepts that as an extension, the result would not be a valid input to execvp, regardless of what the exec'ed program may do, because the argument list must be terminated by a null pointer.